# Free DTD to XSD conversion utility?

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I have a DTD that I need to convert to an XSD (XML schema) file.  Is there a free utility or simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The W3C offers [one](http://www.w3.org/2000/04/schema_hack/). There are also [online converters](http://www.hitsw.com/xml_utilites/).

Comment: The 'online converters' XML Utilities link is currently out-of-date. The tool moved to: [http://www.xmlutilities.net](http://www.xmlutilities.net). But now you'll have to request for access.  I found a link to this tool [http://www.lumrix.net/dtd2xs.php](http://www.lumrix.net/dtd2xs.php)  in an O'REILLY article and it worked well for me (you do need the Java Runtime Environment installed, but most of us still have that :-) ).

Comment: lumrix.net tool also gone

Comment: Good things disappear quickly from the internet.

Comment: There is another version of the W3C tool here http://www.mathling.com/xmlschema/ . Found it here: http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XML_Schema#DTD_to_XSD_Conversion_tools

Comment: The lumrix.net link is also broken/out-of-date.  A Google search on just "dtd2xs.php" turns up quite a few hits, but most are the same link, or sites that I was a little nervous about downloading from...

Comment: Does JDK have command line tool from DTD to XSD conversion?

Comment: The lumrix dtd2xs tool (Java) can be found here: https://github.com/reposit/dtd2xs

This worked for me: `java -cp . dtd2xsd report.dtd > report.xsd`

Comment: W3C tool requires ***Perl installation***

Comment: the w3c one is actually broken, I guess it is too old. it generates invalid xsd.

Answer (score 57):

If you happen to have Visual Studio, open the DTD file an you should have a button to "Create Schema" out of it.

I haven't checked if it was available on Express edition, though.

Comment: Nice, worked perfectly in VS2012. The option is found in the main menu under XML -> Create schema

Comment: Seems supported by the 2015 community edition as well. :)
Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2015 >>> open .dtd file >>> XML tab >>> Create Schema

Answer (score 13):

Try xmlpad from https://download.cnet.com/XmlPad/3000-7241_4-10252051.html to convert DTD to XSD. Really nice tool.

Comment: You need to open a DTD file before you can access the requested functionality (convert DTD to XSD in this case; it can also generate a sample XML). Works great, thanks!

Comment: can't parse the w3c strict.dtd file.

Comment: Site down. Cannot reach.

Comment: Currently, that URL comes up with my firewall flagging it as malware.

Answer (score 12):

http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html

Trang converts between different schema languages for XML. It supports the following languages:

- RELAX NG (XML syntax)
- RELAX NG compact syntax
- XML 1.0 DTDs
- W3C XML Schema

http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang-manual.html

Comment: The website is down.

Comment: The thaiopensource link currently redirects to https://relaxng.org/jclark/trang-manual.html