# When to use DTD vs XSD for validation

Tags: xsd-validation, dtd, xml

I'm bit confused on which scenario is best to use DTD vs XSD and vice versa. I have a requirement to validate cXML Purchase Order file. If anyone could please help, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSD has for all practical purposes superseded DTD and should be used for any new development.  DTD has many limitations (e.g. no real support for data types or XML namespaces).

Comment: Thanks @bobbymc, does cXML Supports XSD? I can't find any XSD for PO and Invoice cXML on http://www.cxml.org/.

Comment: @flybyte - Possibly check http://www.modhul.com/schema-repository-cxml/ or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510126/free-dtd-to-xsd-conversion-utility