# Deserialize XML Messages to Objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I'm writing a client for a protocol that uses HTTP to transport XML messages. It is synchronous because I form an XML document that follows a DTD and send it to a gateway for the protocol via POST with the WebClient class and I get an XML response message from the remote server to indicate transaction state/message ID/etc.

Since I have the DTD, is it possible to create classes with it? There are a handful of possible responses for each type of "operation" my XML message is performing and having classes that could be hydrated by the returned server XML would be advantageous.

Once I have those classes, what are the basic steps to deserializing the XML message from the server into objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Covert the DTD to XSD (not sure if this step is still required) :

[Free DTD to XSD conversion utility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510126/free-dtd-to-xsd-conversion-utility)

Generate C# class from the XSD (command line tool, this is how I do it, not sure if there is a better way) :

http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/quickstart/howto/doc/xmlserialization/XSDToCls.aspx

Serialize back to class from XML :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Comment: This definitely gets me started on what I set out to do. I converted the DTD to XSD using trang and generated classes from the new XSD file. It should be easy to complete the code to serialize and deserialize from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

once you have the xml string, you can do something like this where T is your generic object.

```
public static T GetObjectFromXmlString<T>(string xml)
{
    T result = default(T);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        return result;

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xr);
        }                   
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'll have to try that. Would you happen to have a solution to the other part to my question? I would like a trivial process to generate the classes from the DTD. I'll try Eric H's suggestions but I was hoping .Net or VS2010 would have a tool to assist with that.

Comment: i don't have a better way of generating classes from DTD. I'm not sure of your requirements but if you have to generate it once (dtd is static), i would go with some tool. but if you have to dynamically generate classes, you could read the dtd file and use reflection to create classes or assemblies. just a thought.

Comment: Yeah I went with a tool because it's static since it's a protocol.

Comment: Btw, doesn't the using block close/dispose the StringReader and XmlTextReader? I don't think the explicit close() calls are necessary.

Comment: You are right. I don't think you need it. I'll edit the answer. Also, this is meant to be a sample, please make sure to handle exceptions etc.