# XML to XSD tool for linux

Tags: xml, linux, xsd

What's the best tool out there to create (or to infer) an XSD schema from XML document? I need  it to be linux-compatible.

Comment: Hmm, how would that work? XSD is extremely semantic, and that's something you can't infer from examples.

Comment: I have a simply XML response, and I want to create, based on this XML, a XSD schema. I've found some tools online, like http://www.flame-ware.com/products/xml-2-xsd/ , but I'd like to know if there's something better...

Comment: On windows this is easy as there is a tool in the .net SDK, sorry don't know about unix

Comment: @Let_M_Be, in a lot of cases a tool can create a good enough XSD for a example XML document.  A set of classes for read/writing the xml can them be auto created from the XSD (maybe with a bit of hand editing of the XSD if needed)

Comment: @Let_M_Be: When creating XSD's, It's a huge time saver.  First I get some XML examples, and *convert* to respective XSD's.  Then I combine the appropriate parts together,  and make some hand edits, to make the final XSD.  It's never 100%, as it only covers the your original XML input, but that does not make the process worthless.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the past I have used Trang : http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html

Its old and basic but i find it generates cleaner schemas than other tools (e.g. XMLSpy)

Comment: Finally, trang is the tool we're using to transform a XSD in a DTD, and also the reverse. Thanks!

Comment: On Ubuntu : sudo apt-get install trang ; trang input.xml output.xsd

Comment: This seems to work well. Usage: trang -I xml -O xsd example.xml schema.xsd

Answer (score 3):

You can create a DTD from XML using [DTDGenerator](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/dtdgen.html) from the saxon project. Then you can convert this to a XSD using W3C's [dtd2xsd.pl](http://www.w3.org/2000/04/schema_hack/). See [Free DTD to XSD conversion utility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510126/free-dtd-to-xsd-conversion-utility).

Comment: Thank you.. Perhaps it's a better method convert to DTD and then to XSD than directly to a XSD.

Comment: Wouldn't XML->XSD generally be better than XML->DTD->XSD since XSD is potentially more descriptive? The latter could lead to a less specific XSD.