# How to load complete package with Jaxb with schema

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to load the package with Jaxrb.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.abc");
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
```

But during marshalling I am getting an exception as `com.abc doesn't contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index` .

In some article I found that you have to design the schema, but not found any article on that.

Comment: you need xjc. https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/generate-your-jaxb-classes-in-second/ here is an example

Comment: I have to create a schema using xjc and then I will use JAXB.GETINSTANCE

Comment: thanks Nonika, its really helpful...       xjc -d src -p blog.thoughts.on.java schema.xsd     you can post on answer.

Comment: can you tell me how to create xsd from xml using command line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843388/xml-to-xsd-tool-for-linux