# How do i read through a file to find the content of nested parenthetic symbols using vb.net?

Tags: regex, vb.net, nested-groups

i am using vb.net to convert text files to schemas and not sure where to start.

my source file is a text file with multiple lines like this:

```
<!ELEMENT address      - -  ((street, pobox?, city, state, 
                       zip) | abc | sr+)                 >
```

the desired output is a text file like this:

```
<xs:element name="address">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="street"/>
      <xs:element ref="pobox" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="city"/>
      <xs:element ref="state"/>
      <xs:element ref="zip"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="abc"/>
    <xs:element ref="sr" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:choice>      
</xs:complexType>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1. Your input is not a text file, it looks like a DTD. 2. Your output is not a text file, it looks like an XSD. 3. Ain't there a free converter that already does stuff like that? 4. Such a question is much too broad here.

Comment: you are correct @ThomasWeller. My source file is a sgml dtd and my output will be xsd. I can not find a free converter so i decided to create my own using vb.net and regularexpressions to no avail. any tips?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1510126/480982

Comment: thanks. turns out that visual studio has a converter, but only works with xml dtds.

Comment: So now I'm curious what makes a SGML DTD special from other DTD's. How about you post the DTD so maybe we can help you get an XSD out of it.

Comment: @MrGadget there are many differences ref: http://xml.silmaril.ie/dtdconv.html